# For every row how to add a class name on the <th> based on the value on a particular column using Datatables

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

So I am trying to add a class to a column using the data id. Something like this

```
{ data: 'id' },
{ data: 'Store' },
{ data: 'test','sClass':{ data: 'id' }, },
```

using Datatables. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: sorry... what is the objective here

Comment: I want every row to have a class named after the data.id coming from my server so something like this
<th class = 1234  > ... </th>

Comment: This is really unclear. By "do anything" what do you expect it to do?

Comment: I don't know how is it unclear for you? Am I not explaining it well? For every row I want the class name on the third column to be the value of my first column. Example if the value of the first column is 3 I want my third column class to be 3 such as <th class = 3> </th>

Comment: Your title says add "class to datatables ***columns***" but your comment says you want to add a class to every ***row***.  Which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [createdRow](http://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) property to define callback for whenever a TR element is created.

```
var table_data = [
    { "id": 1, "Store": 2, "test": 3 },
    { "id": 4, "Store": 5, "test": 6 }
];

$('#example').dataTable( {
    "data": table_data,
    "columns" : [
      { "data": "id" },
      { "data": "Store" },
      { "data": "test" }
    ],
    "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ){
        $('td', row).eq(2).addClass('id-' + data['id']);
    }
});
```

Code `$('td', row).eq(2)` is used to select third cell in the table row using zero-based index (`2` for third cell). Code `addClass('id-' + data['id'])` will set that cell `class` attribute to `id-X` where `X` is the value of your `id` field in the dataset. Since class names cannot start with a digit you need to have a prefix that starts with a letter (for example, `'id-'`).

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfhy6397/) or [Row created callback example](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html) for demonstration.

Comment: What is an actual difference between my answer and this one? I'm not arguing or something :) I just want to know why am i downvoted. If I am not right or using `fnRowCallback` is bad I want to know it so that next time I will not use it or recommend using it. Actually, the only difference in this two solutions is using `createdRow` function instead of `fnRowCallback` function. Both of them allow DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate with adding rows by "fnRowCallback".

```
$("#your-id").dataTable({
    "data": data,
    "columns": colModel,
    "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData) {
        $(nRow).attr('data-user-id', aData.UserId); // nRow is a <tr> DOM
        if (aData.isColored) $(nRow).addClass('colored-row'); // aData is a data row
    }
});
```

Then you will have something like this:

```
// ...
<tr class='colored-row' data-user-id="1">
   <td>1</td>
   <td>True</td>
   <td>John</td>
</tr>
<tr data-user-id="2">
   <td>2</td>
   <td>False</td>
   <td>Mike</td>
</tr>
// ...
```

Of course, you can add any other classes, attributes, styles etc.
It is up to your web site needs :)

Comment: I am going to try that out

Comment: Your answer is valid. However `fnRowCallback` callback is deprecated API that may be removed in future versions of DataTables. It is bad practice to mix new options (`data`, `columns`) and previous version options (`fnRowCallback`). Also OP asked how to add a class to a column (not a row) using the data `id` property.